# Fetch related 'far' records by eloquent or fluent

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following tables:

```
users:
------
id
first_name
current_property_id

property_users:
---------------
id
user_id
property_id
chat_user_id
nickname

chat_users:
-----------
id
identity

chat_groups:
------------
id
name
type ['Single' means the group a user is having permutation without repetition for all property users that will serve as their 1:1 conversation (in short everyone is paired with everyone once), 'Group' means more than 2 people can be in the group]
last_messaged_at

chat_group_members:
-------------------
id
chat_group_id
user_id
chat_user_id
```

I need to make a query to fetch all users (except me) in the property I am in and get the chat_groups I have with them (Type == Single).

I tried doing it PHP way but it takes too long (for 125 users it takes +30s of response)

This is how I am doing it in PHP

```php
$this->currentUser = auth()->user();

//this is Fluent using DB::table and joining property_users, chat_users, and users
$propertyUsers = $this->run(GetPropertyUsersJob::class, [
   'property' => $this->property
]); 

//this is using simple eloquent getting groups
$chatGroups = $this->run(GetGroupsJob::class, [
    'property' => $this->property,
    'type' => ChatGroup::TYPE_SINGLE
]);

$chatGroups->load('members.user');

//first level of loop
foreach($propertyUsers as $propertyUser) {
    if($this->currentUser->id == $propertyUser->user_id) {
        return [];
    }

    $chatGroupId = '';
    $chatGroupName = '';
    
    //second level of loop
    foreach($chatGroups as $chatGroup) {
        $found = 0;
        
        //third level of loop
        foreach($chatGroup->members as $member) {
            if($member->user_id == $this->currentUser->id) {
                $found++;
            }

            if($member->user_id == $propertyUser->user_id) {
                $found++;
            }
        }

        //just to get this, I need to do nested loop 3x
        if($found == 2) {
            $chatGroupId = $chatGroup->id;
            $chatGroupName = $chatGroup->name;
        }
    }

    $user[] = [
        'id' => $propertyUser->user_id,
        'first_name' => $propertyUser->user->first_name,
        'nickname' => $propertyUser->nickname,
        'chat_group_id' => $chatGroupId,
        'chat_group_name' => $chatGroupName
    ];
}
```

How can I convert this to a query (eloquent/fluent) instead?

#Update:

```php
User model: I am only adding related eager loading
-----------
public function property_users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PropertyUser::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}


PropertyUser model:
-------------------
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function chat_user()
{
   return $this->hasOne(ChatUser::class, 'id', 'chat_user_id');
}


ChaUser model:
--------------
public function property_user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(PropertyUser::class, 'id', 'chat_user_id');
}
```

Comment: Please share the models in the post too. And what is the difference between chat_users and users?

Comment: @Aashishgaba user contains basic user info, while chat_users contain user chat info like identity it use to connect to chat server and also the chat type whether jabber etc. I have added the models with their related eager loading relationship that I think is related to the question

Comment: And `fetch all users (except me) in the property I am in` by this you mean the users which have `current_propert_id` same as mine?

Comment: Yes and also they must have a record in property_users with same property_id. This is because, a user can be attached to multiple property, but only online in 1 property at a time, that is where the current_property_id comes in

Comment: your relationships look odd. If a `PropertyUser` `hasOne` `ChatUser`, then `chat_users` should have a `property_user_id`, not the other way round. Perhaps you meant `ChatUser` `hasOne` `PropertyUser`? In any case, the key definitions looks odd too. If you have the correct relationships, you can easily achieve your goal using query builder. Start from `ChatGroup` include nested relationships using `with` (so that you can pass conditions to relationship query).

Comment: @user3532758 the direction of relationship is User > PropertyUser > ChatUser that is why in property_users table there is chat_user_id instead the other way around

Comment: @rfpdl Does that mean a `ChatUser` **always** `belongsTo` a `PropertyUser`? As it stands now, that will not happen since `chat_users` table does not have a `property_user_id` field that references property_users table. Current setup allows standalone `ChatUsers` without any link to any model/table. I am insisting on this point because, as I said earlier, I feel like the only way you would have less trouble is fixing the relationships, it would be easier even if you were to construct a raw query, let alone eloquent.

Comment: @user3532758 It belongsTo yes, but at the same time PropertyUser has chat_user relationship too which is `hasOne`. This is because when searching through users in a property, the base model I will use in query is PropertyUsers then I start the eager loading there.